# Using Backpack 4.1 on Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-backpack

We are currently using Laravel Shift to upgrade our old App(5.8). Since there are some functions on shift that would be great to use but apparently the minimum requirement is Laravel 9.

So, I just want to know if Backpack 4.1 is compatible with Laravel 9? Since our app is using Backpack 4.1 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not compatible:

- [Backpack 4.x](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/introduction) supports Laravel 6, 7 and 8
- Backpack 5.x supports Laravel 9, etc.

If you want to use Laravel 9, you’ll have to also upgrade Backpack to v5 - it is a paid upgrade, but it should be a very simple one, not that many breaking changes.